# .BAT file to identify 64/32 bit system

Tags: cmd

I am currently trying to write a .BAT file that runs a particular .exe depending on whether or not the system is 64/32 bit.

So far my code looks like this:

```
cd driver 
SET isX=SYSTEMINFO | find /C "X64-based"
SET isY=SYSTEMINFO | find /C "X32-based"
IF isX == 1 setupX32.exe 
IF isY == 1 setupX64.exe 
cd ..
setup.exe
```

The commands work individually. It seems that there is a problem with assigning a variable while piping. because

> echo %isX%

Doesn't seem to work. Any advise would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou.

~ Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where exactly error is coming?

just a thought.. May be you can use %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% variable to find out the architecture instead of from SYSTEMINFO..

or instead of going for pipe, you can implement if else block/..

Answer (score 1):

64 bit systems have the `PROGRAMFILES(X86)` environmental variable defined, you can test for this;

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
CD DRIVER
IF DEFINED PROGRAMFILES(X86)  (
    SET app=setupX64.exe 
) ELSE (
    SET app=setupX32.exe 
)

START %app%
```